# Action lists sorted by person

Tags: sorting, description, data-structures

I am creating a class for meeting minutes as I have some quite specific demands —`minutes.sty` doesn't seem to meet all of my requirements.

There's some good progress, but I'm completely stuck on the following: I want to be able to define action items as I encounter them in the meetings and have them automatically sorted per person.

It'd be great if I could write something like this:

```
\action{Peter}{next week}{Take out the garbage}

\action{Mike}{tomorrow}{Prepare a presentation for the thing}

\action{Peter}{2015-02-28}{Clean the kitchen}

\action{Peter}{tomorrow}{Water the plants}

\action{Mike}{yesterday}{Cleanse the bathroom}
```

And have it all show up in a `description` environment like this:

```
\begin{description}
  \item[Peter] \hfill \\
     Water the plants     \hfill \textbf{tomorrow} \\
     Take out the garbage \hfill \textbf{next week} \\
     Clean the kitchen    \hfill \textbf{2015-02-28} \\
  \item[Mike] \hfill \\
     Prepare a presentation for the thing \hfill \textbf{tomorrow} \\
     Cleanse the bathroom                 \hfill \textbf{yesterday} \\
\end{description}
```

The tasks needn't be also sorted by due date per person, although I'd love pointers for that as well. Grouping them by person is more critical.

I obviously need a datastructure, but I have no idea where to start or how these would work. Is there something like an array, list, hash map or anything that allows sorting quite easily?

I am also not tied to any particular compiler. If there are features in, say `luatex` that will make this way easier, then that wouldn't be a problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it even possible?

Comment: Related: [How to programmatically create sections in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46548/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\newcounter{personcntr}% Keep track of number of persons
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\action}[3]{% \action{<name>}{<time>}{<duty>}
  \@ifundefined{person@#1}{% If person doesn't exist
    \stepcounter{personcntr}% Next person
    \expandafter\xdef\csname person@#1\endcsname{1}% One time/duty
    \expandafter\xdef\csname person@bynumber@\thepersoncntr\endcsname{#1}% Number person

  }{% Person already exists
    \expandafter\xdef\csname person@#1\endcsname{%
      \number\numexpr\csname person@#1\endcsname+1}% Step number of time/duty
  }%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname person@#1@\csname person@#1\endcsname @time\endcsname{#2}% Store time
  \expandafter\xdef\csname person@#1@\csname person@#1\endcsname @duty\endcsname{#3}% Store duty
  \ignorespaces
}
\gdef\newpar{\par}% \multido doesn't enjoy \par

\newcommand\printactions{% Print actions
  \def\descriptionBODY{}% Empty descriptionBODY
  {\let\item\relax% Prevent expansion of \item
   \let\newpar\relax% Prevent expansion of \newpar
    \multido{\iPerson=1+1}{\value{personcntr}}{% Step through all persons
      % Extract person name
      \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\thisperson\expandafter{\csname person@bynumber@\iPerson\endcsname}%
      \protected@xdef\descriptionBODY{%
        \descriptionBODY%
        \item[\thisperson] \leavevmode\newpar}% Add person name to descriptionBODY
      % Extract person number
      \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\thispersonnum\expandafter{\csname person@\thisperson\endcsname}%
      \multido{\iDuty=1+1}{\thispersonnum}{%
        \protected@xdef\descriptionBODY{%
          \descriptionBODY%
          \csname person@\thisperson @\iDuty @duty\endcsname% Add person duty to descriptionBODY
          \hfill
          {\bfseries\csname person@\thisperson @\iDuty @time\endcsname}% Add person time to descriptionBODY
          \newpar
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  % Print person time/duty
  \begin{description}
    \descriptionBODY
  \end{description}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\action{Peter}{next week}{Take out the garbage}

\action{Mike}{tomorrow}{Prepare a presentation for the thing}

\action{Peter}{2015-02-28}{Clean the kitchen}

\action{Peter}{tomorrow}{Water the plants}

\action{Mike}{yesterday}{Cleanse the bathroom}

\printactions

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If anyone reading this is interested in the package, it can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/StickyUtrecht/sticky.tex).

Comment: This is great @Werner! Any way to have the names of the people in different colours? This would be in the main document, not the printactions list.
Eg. Peter in red and Mike in blue and it would print "\red{Peter:} Take out the garbage"

Comment: @James: What about an input like `\action[red]{Peter}{<when>}{<what>}`? This would allow you to specify different colours, even for the same person (with the default - if colour is unspecified - being `black`). Or would you always have (say) `Peter` in `red` so you only have to specify it once. So many choices! :)

Comment: Too true --can add an extra argument. It'd be nice to have it automagical, though!

Comment: @James: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/7dEdj6qU). It provides `\colourperson{Peter}{blue}`.

Comment: @Werner, thanks! I was trying to mod it to make the text print the name of the action in the body at the right colour, instead of just at the list. I tried this after the first \ignorespaces: \noindent\textbf{@color #1:} #3 \hfill \textit{#2}, but couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @James: You should provide some code...